# How to convert txt file to Json objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, type-conversion, data-conversion

I have questions which are stored in a `json` file, something like this:

```
{
   "minecraft":{
        "14272827390549425":{
            "questions":"",
            "answer": ""
        },
        "etc."
   },
   "fortnite":{
   },
   "etc.":{
   }
}
```

I have a different `txt` file for each game and they're filled out like this:

```
question:answer
question:answer
```

Is there a way to convert those `txt` files into `json` objects matching the format above?

(the names of the objects are generated random by my code)

Comment: JSON => JavaScript Object Notation. There is no such thing as 'JSON object'.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, your easiest option would be to convert it somewhere online, where the solution for this problem already exists. 
Maybe try [this](https://pdfmall.com/txt-to-json)

Comment: you think i havent seached a bit first (6 hours spent for nothing good)